# C++ unknown type when initialise vector from static constexpr

Tags: c++, vector, constexpr, typename

C++ gcc compiler gives unclear error when compile:

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class A
{
  constexpr static int i = 10;
  vector<int>m(i);
};

int main()
{
  return 0;
}
```

I compile with:   g++ var_test.cc -o var_test -std=c++0x
Result:

```
var_test.cc:8:16: error: unknown type name 'i'
vector<int>m(i);
```

Why is it unknown? C++0x should have in place member initialization

Comment: Why not use c++11 or c++14 now ?

Comment: due to cross-compatibility issues

Comment: `m` is a member function declaration, not a data member.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++11 does support in-place non-static member initialization, but to use it you need a *brace-or-equal-initializer*, i.e. one of these forms:

```
vector<int> m {i};
vector<int> m = vector<int>(i);
vector<int> m = vector<int>{i};
```

Using parentheses isn't supported as it looks too much like a function declaration.